# How to handle distro versions in Yocto

Tags: version, versioning, software-distribution, yocto

I'm looking for some advice on how to properly handle versioning when managing a distro using [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/).

I have several embedded systems in production and have to rely on a third party to apply updates. Updates include one or more `.ipk` packages that get installed via [opkg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opkg). I have no control over when the third parties apply the update(s) I send them. This introduces the issue I am trying to find a solution to. The systems are likely to be in various different states as some updates are applied and others are not. Is there a common solution to tell what state a system is in?

One problem I'm not clear on is how ensure the embedded system has certain updates applied before applying further updates. How do distros such as Ubuntu or Redhat handle this? Or do they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu and RedHat have a remote repositories. The systems have a internal list of installed packages. When you update the repository you get a new list of packages. You can then compare this list of installed packages against the new package list and install them. This is basically done with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and the yum equivalent.

Yocto actually supports rpm and deb package format and their remote repositories. I am not familiar with opkg and if they have the option of a remote repository.

When I implemented a system I narrowed it down to the following options:

- have a repository (deb and rpm definitely work here)
- have a version package
- using images

Version packages have the big disadvantages since you have to get your own logic on which packages to install. But you can require that version-1.deb needs software-v2.deb and tool-v1_5.deb. That works well with you own software but is a big manual overhead for the entire Yocto package stack.

Repository would be the usual way such as: `apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade`. Works well and easy, but lacks also a risk free path to newer Yocto version.

The image way is more complicated and depends on your used hardware, size of image and transfer of the image. If you have a huge image and a slow network you might not want to do this. Basically you push your new image (or automatically pull it based on a version) d push it then to the device. The device dd's it to a secondary partition and then you flip the bootload to use the other partition. Depending on bootloader and/or hardware you can automatically flip back in case the partition you booted in is broken. Helpful for remote systems. Advantage is: you can also easily upgrade the entire OS without manually picking versions. And you can have (automatic) fail-over.

Comment: There's a software suite called [mender](https://mender.io/), which I've used with success to implement the full image updates mentioned here.